# Partial term search for a field with "/" special character in azure cognitive search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am seeing some issues when trying to search for a field that has “/” special character in it in Azure Search.

I am listing the queries I have tried below, so looking for help in figuring out the issue.

There is a field called `CustomProperty` with keyword analyzer, so the field doesn’t get tokenized on special characters.

[CustomPropertyWithKeywordAnalyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhq6T.png)

The value of customProperty is `objectId/70efb434-40c4-4314-a53c-179700480ca8`

`search=/.*object.*70ef.*/&queryType=full&searchFields=customProperty`
**query works**

[QueryResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJiG9.png)

`search=/.*70efb434-40c4-4314-a53c-179700480ca8.*/&queryType=full&searchFields=customProperty`
**query works**

[QueryResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuBxl.png)

Starts to get near to “/” the query doesn’t work, while “object.*” query works above.
`search=/.*objectI.*70ef.*/&queryType=full&searchFields=customProperty`
**doesn’t work**

[QueryResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH7Lp.png)

`search=/.*objectI.*/&queryType=full&searchFields=customProperty`
**doesn’t work**

[QueryResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw8an.png)

`search=/.*objectId\/70efb4.*/&queryType=full&searchFields=customProperty`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-partial-matching#about-partial-term-search says to escape / with , but that also doesn’t work.
**doesn’t work**

[QueryResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLprt.png)

simple(not full-lucene) also **doesn't work**
`search=objectId\/70efb4*&searchFields=customProperty`

[QueryResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfKFf.png)

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're running into isn't caused by the `/` but instead is caused by a mismatch in the casing between your query and the data in your index. Partial term searches, like the regex searches that you're doing, are automatically lowercased. However, they keyword analyzer you're using doesn't lowercase the text. That means that in your index, the data looks like `objectId` but your query is being automatically lowercased to `objectid`. That mismatch is what's causing your query to not return results. There are more details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-query-partial-matching

For your use case, I'd recommend the following analyzer:

```json
"analyzers": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
            "name": "custom-keyword",
            "tokenizer": "keyword_v2",
            "tokenFilters": [
                "lowercase"
            ],
            "charFilters": []
        }
    ]
```

I tested your queries with that analyzer and that sample data and they all worked using that analyzer.

Comment: Thanks Derek, this definitely helps :) Regarding "Partial term searches, like the regex searches that you're doing, are automatically lowercased." Is there any option to prevent partial term searches to get lowercased by default?

Comment: There's not a way to prevent partial term searches from being lowercased. If you wanted to do something similar in a way that's case sensitive, you could create a custom analyzer with ngrams and then use standard keyword searches. This doc gives an example of such an analyzer, you would need to remove the lowercase tokenFilter though: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-query-partial-matching#tune-query-performance